# Why Visual Studio cannot find 'tr1/unordered_map?

Tags: visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-2005, tr1, unordered-map

I want to use google-ctemplate in a project. But if I include the basic file, I get the following error (with Visual Studio C++ 2005):

```
Error   1   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tr1/unordered_map': No such file or directory f:\entwicklung\libraries\ctemplate-0.99\src\ctemplate\template_cache.h  39
```

I can find the unordered_map.hpp in the boost-directory and the boost-directory is set in the include-path in Visual Studio. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. I included the wrong directory from google-ctemplate. Instead of `src` I have to use `src/windows`.

But that triggers another Problem, this time from the linker.

Answer (score 0):

As is, you can use:

```
#include <boost/tr1/unordered_map.hpp>
```

Alternatively, add your $(boost-directory)/boost/tr1/tr1 to the include path and use:

```
#include <unordered_map>
```

See this [Header Include Style](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_tr1/usage.html#boost_tr1.usage.include_style) for more details.

Note: I'm assuming $(boost-directory) is set to something like "C:\boost_1_46_0".

Answer (score 0):

Considering that TR1 was not published until the summer of 2005, I wouldn't be surprised that it isn't present in VS 2005. You might try a more up-to-date version of the compiler!